# Quickblox requestBuilder [or]

Tags: java, android, arraylist, quickblox, custom-object

```
requestBuilder.or("userPhone",myPhone,phoneList);
        }
    }

    QBCustomObjects.getObjects("image", requestBuilder, new QBCallbackImpl() {
```

"phoneList" is arrayList of Strings.
now on my device this code work well but on samsung devices i have crash :
"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 147: https://api.quickblox.com/data/image.."

now i know for sure that the arrayList making the problem, because if i put instead of phoneList just , "00000", "09878889" - it's work fine.
what to do?
thanks..

Edit:

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
            HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
            hs.addAll(phoneList);
            al.clear();
            al.addAll(hs);

            String[]arrString = new String [al.size()+1];
            for (int j = 0; j < al.size(); j++) {
                String str = al.get(j).toString();
                arrString[j+1]= str;
            }
            arrString[0]= myPhone;
            requestBuilder.or("userPhone",arrString);
```

this is my solution, but i discovered that if "arrString" is bigger than 600+ it's doesn't work, why is that?

Comment: Igor, please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain how **OR** operator works:

1) for example, you have **name** field

To get all records with name Alex OR Garry use next query:

```
requestBuilder.or("name", "Alex", "Garry");
```

2)  for example, you have **name** field and **age** field

To get all records with name Alex OR age 22 use next query:

```
requestBuilder.or("name", "Alex");
requestBuilder.or("age", "22");
```

Try somtehing like this

Comment: thanks, i understand that, but if i want:
requestBuilder.or("name", "Alex", "Garry","Leon","Yohan","Nora".....);
and more names?
i'v put all the names in arraylist, as i say, it's work on my device, but on other deevice i need to put all names on String array 
but it's work just if the String array is less than 600+...